# JPA 2 + Criteria API + get oldest element in subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have two entities (`Dataset` and `Item`), where the first one contains a list of the latter one.

```
@Entity
class Dataset {
    @Id long id;
    List<Item> items;
}

@Entity
class Item {
    @Id long id;
    @Temporal Date date;
    String someCriteria;
}
```

I am now looking for **any dataset**, which references an item with **someCriteria = 'x'** as **oldest item** in the dataset's list (it's date is before that of all others referenced by this dataset).

This should work with the Criteria API of JPA-2.0, but an answer as SQL-query would be fine, too.

This is how it looks like right now:

```
Subquery<Item> _subquery = p_criteria.subquery(Item.class);
Root<Item> _itemRoot = _subquery.from(Item.class);
_subquery.select(_itemRoot);

// correlate
_subquery.correlate(_datsetRoot);

// type check
Predicate _typeP = p_builder.equal(_itemRoot.get(Item_.someCriteria), "x");

<additional predicates>
...

// reference check
_subquery.where(_typeP);

return p_builder.exists(_subquery);
```

I though about creating a subquery, order it by date and check the first one. Unfortunately JPA-2.0 does not allow ordering in subqueries (or joins) (as far as I can see). My second idea was getting `MAX(date)`, which should be supported by most of the databases. Same goes here, support for MAX, ABS, ... is only available for numbers.

**EDIT:** Using a subquery, which is sorted, it would look like this (MSSQL):

```
SELECT d.id
FROM Dataset d
WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT TOP 1 *
 FROM Item i
 WHERE i.dataset_id = d.FALL_ID
    AND i.someCriteria = 'x'
 ORDER BY i.date
)
ORDER BY d.FALL_ID
```

(How) could I do this in JPA-2.0?

Comment: I don't belive that there is no solution for this kind of problem. Does nobody have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 1.6 there are the methods [`CriteriaBuilder.least(expression)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#least%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) (instead of `min()`) and [`CriteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(expressionA, expressionB)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lessThanOrEqualTo%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%2C%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29) (instead of `le()`), which work for java.util.Date fields.

In Java 1.5 it seems that there is no way to achive it without additional fields in the DB.

Comment: CriteriaBuilder is not part of Java 6 (=Java 1.6), but of JPA 2.0, which is itself part of Java EE 6. There is no Criteria API (and as such no CriteriaBuilder) in Java 5 (=Java 1.5), JPA 1 or Java EE 5.